# Python 3.7 builtins.NameError

Tags: python, error-handling

right now I'm just studying basic things like list and such, but I encountered a problem while writing my code:

```
from typing import List


def greatest_difference(nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> int:
    """Return the greatest absolute difference between numbers at
    corresponding positions in nums1 and nums2.

    Precondition: len(nums1) == len(nums2) and nums1 != []

    >>> greatest_difference([1, 2, 3], [6, 8, 10])
    7
    >>> greatest_difference([1, -2, 3], [-6, 8, 10])
    10
    """
difference = 0
diff_over_term = 0
for i in range(len(nums1)):
    diff_over_term = abs(nums1[i] - nums2[i])
if diff_over_term > difference:
        difference = diff_over_term
print(difference)
```

For some reason, it says

> builtins.NameError: name `nums1` is not defined

I tried to play with the indents, but it didn't help.

Comment: You need to indent the lines of code that are part of your function. `nums1` is an argument of your function and is only defined in that scope. Because you did not indent the following lines, they're not in the scope of the function either, hence `nums1` is not defined. Also, unrelated, but you should be retirning and `int` no?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ Do not edit the source code in the question; you fixed the error the OP was trying to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't indented the contents of the function. Try this:

```
from typing import List


def greatest_difference(nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> int:
    """Return the greatest absolute difference between numbers at
    corresponding positions in nums1 and nums2.

    Precondition: len(nums1) == len(nums2) and nums1 != []

    >>> greatest_difference([1, 2, 3], [6, 8, 10])
    7
    >>> greatest_difference([1, -2, 3], [-6, 8, 10])
    10
    """
    difference = 0
    diff_over_term = 0
    for i in range(len(nums1)):
        diff_over_term = abs(nums1[i] - nums2[i])
    if diff_over_term > difference:
        difference = diff_over_term
    return difference

# and now call your function, notice how these lines aren't indented, that means they are not part of the function definition
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [6, 8, 10]
print(greatest_difference(list_a, list_b)
```